# MySQLi, why fetch? Safest way to check query?

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

For an login-system I wanna check if username and password are correct, this is the code(without checking errors etc):

```
$db = @new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
$sql = 'SELECT
            id
        FROM
            members
        WHERE
            username = ? AND
            password = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password_hash);
$stmt->execute()
$stmt->bind_result($UserID);
```

Now i want to check if there was a result, in most tutorials its done this way:

```
if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
    //LOGIN WAS INCORRECT, DO STUFF
} else {
    //LOGIN WAS CORRECT, DO STUFF
}
```

But why? It works this way too:

```
if (isset($UserID)){
    //LOGIN WAS CORRECT, DO STUFF
} else {
    //LOGIN WAS INCORRECT, DO STUFF
```

or:

```
if ($UserID != 0){
    //LOGIN WAS CORRECT, DO STUFF
} else {
    //LOGIN WAS INCORRECT, DO STUFF
```

So what is the fastest and safest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need nor "fastest" (as there is nothing to be slow) nor "safest" (as there is nothing to be unsafe).

What you need is just a *sensible* way.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password_hash);
$stmt->execute()
$stmt->bind_result($UserID);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Now you have `$UserID` variable to check and to save it into session.

```
if ($UserID) {
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $UserID;
}
```

as you can see, raw mysqli is very wordy and ugly to use. that's why you shouldn't use it but some abstraction layer like this

```
$db = new safeMysql();
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ?s AND password = ?s';
if ($UserID = $db->getOne($sql, $username, $password_hash));
    $_SESSION['auth'] = $UserID;
}
```